# is it possible to cache pdf file in web page?

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, caching, cache-control

I have a jsp page that is used to download pdf file from server. When I request the jsp page from browser, the jsp read file info from database, get inputstream from file and write to ServletOutputStream. 
The pseudo-code like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline;filename=URLEncoder.encode(filename)");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","max-age=3600");
ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
int size = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
while((size=in.read(buffer))!=-1){
  os.write(buffer,0,size);
}
```

when the request finished, the downloaded pdf was opened in browser. The same file is downloaded many times, so we want to cache them to the local file system, so that each request's return status code is 304(not modified), but the cache-control doesn't work, is there anybody can help?

Comment: Your code is building the response, so your code would have the task to send a 304.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is typically solved by a reverse proxy like NGINX or Varnish in front of your application. Alternatively you can use a CDN.